# 空のCOMクラスライブラリ（C#）を、VBAから初期化してから解放すると、Excelが再起動する（短時間では再起動しない）

Tags: c#, vba, excel, com

お世話になります。

ExcelのVBAから、C#で作成したCOMライブラリを使用したく、
先ず、C#のコードを以下の様にしました。
（VS2019を管理者権限にて起動し、新規プロジェクトより、C#-クラスライブラリ(.netframework 4.8)にて、AAA.csとして実装）

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace clsLibZZZ
{
    [Guid("xxxxxxxx-xxxx ...xxxx")] - (1)
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IAAA
    {
        //
    }

    [Guid("xxxxxxxx-xxxx ...xxxx")] - (2)
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    public interface IAAAEvents
    {
        //
    }

    [Guid("xxxxxxxx-xxxx ...xxxx")] - (3)
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IAAAEvents))]
    public class AAA : IAAA
    {
        public AAA()
        {
            //
        }
        ~AAA()
        {
            //
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
        }

    }
}
```

※ (1)(2)(3)はそれぞれ違うGUID値をVS2019のツール「GUIDの作成」からコピー／貼り付けしております。

プロジェクトのプロパティにて、
　・「アセンブリをCOM参照可能にする」にチェックを入れ、
　・「COM相互運用機能の登録」にチェックを入れ、

ビルドの構成マネージャーにて、
　・プラットフォームを x64 に設定
し、コンパイルしました。

Debug/Releaseフォルダとも、
　・clsLibZZZ.dll
　・clsLibZZZ.tlb
が出来る事を確認しております。

Excel(Excel365 64bit)を起動し、「開発」タブのVisualBasicを開き、
「参照設定」にて、(上記で作成された)"clsLibZZZ.tlb"を追加します。
（特に問題は起こらず、clsLibZZZにチェックが付きます）

VBAProjectを右クリックして、「挿入」→「クラスモジュール」を追加します。

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents XYZ As clsLibZZZ.AAA

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Set XYZ = New AAA

End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()

    Set XYZ = Nothing

End Sub
```

次に、VBAProjectを右クリックして、「挿入」→「標準モジュール」を追加します。

```
Option Explicit

Private cls1 As Class1

Public Sub InitClass()

    Set cls1 = New Class1

End Sub

Public Sub ReleaseClass()

    Set cls1 = Nothing

End Sub
```

適当なファイル名を付けて、Excelマクロ(xlsm)を保存し、VisualBasicの画面を閉じます。

Excelのシートの画面に戻ったら、「開発」タブの「マクロ」から InitClass を実行します。
そのまま、**5分ほど放置**します。
その後、「開発」タブの「マクロ」から ReleaseClass を実行します。
Excelを右上の[×]にて、終了します。

しばらく待つと、Excelが「Book1」として、再起動してしまいます。
但し、「5分待つ」を「10秒待つ」だとExcelの再起動はありません。

【動作確認環境】

Windows10 Pro(64bit) + Excel365(Office365) 64bit
Windows11 Pro(64bit) + Excel2019 64bit

この現象について、色々と調べてみましたが、Excelが再起動する原因と解消する方法が分かりませんでした。
何か分かる方がご教授を頂きたく、よろしくお願いいたします。

追伸

何故「空」なのか？を問う方も居られるかと思います。
　当初はC#で通信プログラムを組み、COMライブラリとする事で、VBAから扱う事を目的としていました。
　この通信プログラムとのやりとりには問題が無かったものの、しばらく通信ログを取り、Excelを終了した後に再起動が確認されました。
　リソースの解放不足かと思ったのですが。色々とやっている内に「空」でも発生する事が分かった次第です。

Comment: ファイナライザ `~AAA()` を削除した場合はどうなりますか？ 空だからこそ.NET GCはこのオブジェクトを削除してしまいそうな気がしました。

Comment: 取り敢えずこんな記事をそのまま作成・実行してみて、質問の状況と比べてみてはどうでしょう？ [【ExcelVBA】ExcelからC#で作成したDLLを呼び出す方法（COM経由／COMインターフェース）](https://devnote.page/excelvba-call-cs-dll/), [C# EXCEL・DLLを作ってVBAで使う](https://cozver.com/2022/10/10/post-2564/)

Comment: @sayuri さん、ありがとうございます。
~AAA() を削除してみましたが。結果は変わりませんでした。

Comment: @kunif さん、ありがとうございます。
既に全く同じ事を先に済ませておりまして。そのまま作成・実行してみたところ、問題は起きませんでした。
しかしながら。こちらの記事では、イベントによる通知も無く。また、処理も一瞬で終了する事から（短時間だと問題は起きないと）一緒だと思われます。
他にもGitHubやQiita等のサンプルも見て回って（無論、必要と思ったのは試してみて）、解消する方法が得られない／見つからないので、こちらに投稿した次第です。
（もし、当方が意図をくみかねていましたら、申し訳ありません）

Comment: 質問のソースコードのようにほぼ実体のないものでも再現するけれども、類似の紹介記事では再現しないのであれば、その差異であるイベント通知インタフェース(IAAAEvents)の定義とclassへの属性指定の有無とか VBA での WithEvents が影響しているのでは？ 質問のソースコードからいったんそれらを外してイベント無しで作成・テストしてみて状況が変わるのか変わらないのか確認してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: @kunif さん、ありがとうございます。
仰る事はよく分かるのですが。C#-COMライブラリから「イベントにて通知」という要求なんですよね。
（元になった通信プログラムにおいて、受信した事をイベントで通知というのを要求されております）
だから、VBA側の WithEvents が外せないのです。
（VBAでイベント通知を受け取るのに WithEvents を使う以外で方法は無いですよね）
少し前後しますが。
質問に投稿したＣ＃ソースのイベント部分をバッサリ削除し、VBAでもWithEventsをコメント等にして使わない様にすると、５分以上放置でもExcelの再起動はありませんでした。
（だからと言って、解消しないのが辛いところです）

Comment: 発生する条件がイベントに関連する何かであると少し絞り込めた訳ですので、それに関する情報が有るか、根本の原因は何か、どう対策すれば良いのか、等を調べる手段や情報はあるのか？といったことを整理して、この質問に追記してブラッシュアップするか、イベント関連でまとめたものを新規の質問として起こすかしてみると良いでしょう。

Comment: @kunri さん、ありがとうございます。
そうですね。整理し直してみます。ありがとうございました。